# What is the difference between an application controller and an application context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture

These terms are similar, and both involve application architecture, but it'd be helpful for new devs to have the difference clearly spelled out in one place.

Comment: Not sure why you felt that `Application Context` and `Controller` are similar terms. `Application Context` is a Core Spring framework term. The purpose of an `Application Context` is to provide the necessary configuration information for initializing the Spring Dependency Injection container (after all, that is what Spring Core is). A `Controller` is a Spring MVC term, where Spring MVC is a Spring module designed for web applications and built on top of Spring Core. The purpose of a controller is to intercept web requests and generating output appropriate for the requests.

Answer (score 0):

The context points to the data store that holds the information generally in shapes specified by the model. The controller facilitates interaction with the context by providing models of the content to the view. Model-View-Controller.